# Why is my portable WD My Passport drive not recognized?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, external-hard-drive

My Western Digital My Passport portable drive is not recognized in OS X. It used to be recognized, but not anymore. It does not appear in `/Volumes`.

The hard drive *is* recognized by a Linux machine. I am not sure what happened — any ideas how to fix that?

```
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            749.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MY PASSPORT             1.0 TB     disk1s1
```

Comment: What do you see in Disk Utility?

Comment: What happens when you type `diskutil mount /dev/disk1s1`?